# Assigning Roles to Users in C# ASP.NET Web Forms

Tags: c#, asp.net

I can't seem to get authorization to work in web.config for user authentication.

I have this in web.config and I tried to do authentication using

```
<authorization>
    <allow roles="Admin" />
    <deny users="*" />  
  </authorization>
```

and this how i get authentication

```
    FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(txtUsername.Text,false);
```

Where do I assign Admin to the user so that it is recognized in the web config?

Answer (score 0):

Well whatever you are using is right but half of the code

```
<forms loginUrl="Login.aspx">
  </forms>
<location path="HRpages">
  <system.web> 
    <authorization>
      <allow roles="HR" />
      <deny users="*" />
    </authorization>
   </system.web>
</location>
```

These two are also to be included in webconfig for more info refer to this

```
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13872/%2FArticles%2F13872%2FForm-authentication-and-authorization-in-ASP-NET
```